# How can i replace image masking in for-loop with logical indexing in python?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, indexing

I am trying to track an object in a video by its color. Can i simplify this code:

```
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        break
    height, width, channel = frame.shape
    hue = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)
    for i in range(width):
        for j in range(height):
            if (hue[j, i, 0] < 110 or hue[j, i, 0] > 140):
                hue[j, i, 0] = 0
                hue[j, i, 1] = 0
                hue[j, i, 2] = 0
```

Comment: What do the [numpy docs on logical indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.indexing.html) not answer for you? Try out the examples there and if there are particular points of confusion with those, post those explicitly.

Comment: Anyways `hue[(hue < 110) | (hue > 140)] = 0` is what you're looking for. Edit: Actually the solution below takes note of the fact that you were only masking based on the first channel, I missed that --- go with that.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds OP is indexing only along the first channel of `hue`. So, we need `hue[...,0]` there.

Comment: @Divakar just noticed and edited accordingly right as you commented!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the two nested for-loops with [`masking`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays), like so -

```
hue[(hue[...,0] < 110) | (hue[...,0] >140)]  = 0
```

This works because the mask created with `(hue[...,0] < 110) | (hue[...,0] >140)` would be of same shape as the first two dims of `hue` and that would be used for masking into `hue` as it indexes along the first two dims of it and applies for all the elements along the last axis. This does the job of three steps assignments : `hue[j, i, 0] = 0; hue[j, i, 1] = 0; hue[j, i, 2] = 0;` in one go.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i went through the documentation, but as I'm new to python, it was too overwhelming.